# Ruby on Rails - minitest assert_select test passes with any parsed JSON, even when it should fail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, assert, minitest

I can't seem to make my test fail with phony data, so that tells me I'm not properly testing my actual data. My view displays a parsed JSON response (which I've verified in the browser), but I can't seem to verify this in a test.

```
# Arrange
account = accounts(:good_account) # from fixture
expected_data = { "status": "SUCCESS" }.to_json
phony_data = { "bestBearType": "BLACK" }.to_json

# Act
get some_show_url(account.id)

# Assert
assert_select 'p', JSON.parse(expected_data) # passes
assert_select 'p', JSON.parse(phony_data) # passes (shouldn't)
assert_select 'p', { "bestBearType": "BLACK" } # passes (shouldn't)
assert_select 'p', expected_data # fails
```

I'm really scratching my head as to how the phony data could be passing. It's almost as if I just have `assert_select 'p'` without the expected value that follows. Is there an issue using parsed JSON here?

Comment: It's really unclear what you're trying to do with `{ "status": "SUCCESS" }`. Are you trying to match something like `<p status="success">`? That's not valid HTML. To be clear, JSON has nothing to do with `assert_select`, which is for working with HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there an issue using parsed JSON here?

You're misusing `assert_select`, which has nothing to do with JSON, it's for selecting HTML elements from your server's output. I can't tell what your intent is here, but you can't query parsed (or unparsed) JSON to `assert_select`, or send JSON as any of its arguments.

In each of your four cases, the behavior of `assert_select` is as expected:

- > `assert_select 'p', JSON.parse(expected_data) # passes`

  You passed it an unknown option, `"status"`. That's not an option supported by `assert_select`, so in effect you're running `assert_select 'p'`, which passes because it finds a `<p>`.

  When given a hash as its second argument, the options it understands are:

  > :text - Narrow the selection to elements that have this text value
  >   (string or regexp).
  >
  > :html - Narrow the selection to elements that have this HTML content
  >   (string or regexp).
  >
  > :count - Assertion is true if the number of selected elements is equal
  >   to this value.
  >
  > :minimum - Assertion is true if the number of selected elements is at
  >   least this value.
  >
  > :maximum - Assertion is true if the number of selected elements is at
  >   most this value.
- > `assert_select 'p', JSON.parse(phony_data) # passes (shouldn't)`

  Yes, this should pass, for the same reason: You're passing a random unknown option that is ignored, and a `<p>` is found to match.
- > `assert_select 'p', { "bestBearType": "BLACK" } # passes (shouldn't)`

  As above, yes, this should pass, "bestBearType" is not a valid option for `assert_select`.
- > `assert_select 'p', expected_data # fails`

  This *should* fail, because the second argument you're giving it is a string, which matches as follows:

  > Assertion is true if the text value of at least one element matches the string or regular expression.

  There is no `<p>` tag in your output that matches the string `"{\"status\": \"SUCCESS\"}"`.

See [the documentation](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.1/classes/ActionDispatch/Assertions/SelectorAssertions.html#method-i-assert_select) for a complete description and some useful examples.

Comment: I see I didn't clearly convey my intention for why I'm looking for parsed JSON on the page, so I added this to the post: `My view displays a parsed JSON response (which I've verified in the browser), but I can't seem to verify this in a test.` Your answer helped me understand `assert_select` better, and helped me realize I was targeting the wrong key in my parsed JSON. And because `assert_select` doesn't have an `option` corresponding to the key I was checking, I was getting a `pass`. So by coincidence my parsed JSON was being interpreted as a hash with options by `assert_select`. Thank you!